# In angular 5.2.1 production getting ...ules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.cssNode#moveTo was deprecated. Use Container#append

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

See below version info and `package.json`

**version:**

`ng-version="5.2.1"`

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "experiment",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

**commands:**

1) `ng build`  : here I am not getting any warnings

2) `ng build --prod` : here I am getting:

> 10% building modules 4/6 modules 2 active
>   ...ules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.cssNode#moveTo was deprecated.
>   Use Container#append. Date: 2018-01-23T06:19:48.732Z Hash:
>   34c92447878ca7d7b148 Time: 150966ms chunk {0}
>   polyfills.39c2675f132c0f995f11.bundle.js (polyfills) 59.5 kB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {1} main.5222b9447b8051d66fa2.bundle.js (main) 728 kB
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {2} styles.b635c6f169c366ff5b2f.bundle.css
>   (styles) 217 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {3}
>   inline.676417dc826d752b57e1.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry]
>   [rendered]

I googled, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8598 got this, still, i didn't get a solution.

Comment: Please Check if there is any inconsistency with the packages installed, and the new ones. You probably need to upgrade your Angular. Use the following command, and paste the output in comment ->
npm install -g npm-check-updates

Comment: Thanks for your time, Checked with this command still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

This command is to see the package difference and not to fix any issue., I`ll suggest you to delete your node_modules folder and execute this command

```
 ncu -u
```

and

```
npm install --save
```

to update your package.json. Once done with it, try with

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with above commands, All packages updated.
But when I do `ng build --prod` this its showing Same error with 
`ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error`

Comment: Try removing ^ symbol from  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7", in your package.json file. If upgraded, it might have a different version. Once done, delete node_modules and run npm install again.

Comment: :( You know after that update, bootstrap got updated then my project got disturbed. Again I downgraded bootstrap.

Comment: After removing ^ symbol also same :  `10% building modules 3/6 modules 3 active ...ules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.cssNode#moveTo was deprecated. Use Container#append.`

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to use 3.3.7, I mean an upgrade would not throw any problem. There is however an alternative way to include bootstrap, all you need to do is remove bootstrap from package.json, and in your index.html,  add `<link
 href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 rel="stylesheet" />` inside your <head> tag, delete node_modules, and do npm install

Comment: Ok still after the update I tried `ng build --prod` still throwing the same issue.

Comment: In order to remove bootstrap use `npm uninstall bootstrap`

Comment: In this project, i included bootstrap & material icons, and uninstalled bootstrap and then run --prod command still have the same issue with material icons and then again I uninstalled material icons still have the same issue with style.css. it's like switching that issue with existing CSS file.

Comment: Did you link material Icons in index.html?? `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: no, i installed using  `npm install material-design-icons`. Anyway I removed that from project and tried with --prod command still showing the same issue. `10% building modules 4/5 modules 1 active ...pp\htdocs\homelane.com\src\styles.cssNode#moveTo was deprecated. Use Container#append.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163697/discussion-between-rahul-and-raghavendra-s).

Answer (score 0):

Please update "@angular/cli" to "1.7.3"

Step 1: npm remove @angular/cli
Step 2: npm cache clean --force
Step 3: npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.3

Still stuck then update your package.json with

"@angular/cli": "1.7.3" and run npm install

Tested and working for me

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by doing RND. And finally got solution by  removing deprecated css in my project.

For example `.section{color:#ddd;} .section{font-size:14px}` this is deprecated css and I changed to`.section{color:#ddd; font-size:14px}`

And I customisd my bootstrap css for example I copied css which are all usefull to my project to my style.css.

It's worked for me.